# How to start Spring Boot server with ClassRule in JUnit4?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit4

As I can see the there is the  `org.springframework.test.context.junit4.rules.SpringClassRule` that is a `ClassRule`'s equivalent to the `org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

However, I'd like to boot up my *whole Spring Boot application* with a `ClassRule`. Is there something like `org.springframework.boot.test.contextSpringBootTest` as a `ClassRule`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a GitHub project that solves this issue: https://github.com/CarloWakefield/spring-boot-test-rule

Comment: There was -- link is dead.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg The GitHub account seems to be deleted.